# How to Update with subquery in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a function in MS SQL Server just like this:

```
UPDATE r
SET
    monthly =
(
    SELECT SUM(-h.value_ini - h.purchase + h.sold + h.value_fin)
    FROM   hist_portfolio AS h
    WHERE  h.comp_id = r.comp_id
     AND h.port_id = r.port_id 
     AND h.exte_id = r.cate_id
     AND h.type_id = @type_rel_aux
     AND h.hcar_day > @date_month_before
     AND h.hcar_day <= @date_base
)
   FROM   #Month_Table r
   WHERE  type = 1;
```

and thats the result (after update):

```
    Seq     monthly 
   2        102471,34
   1        -5129,46
   3        -29841,23
   4        0
```

But when I execute the same update in a fuction in PostgreSQL, all the rows get the same value:

```
UPDATE Month_Table
    SET variacao_mes_rs = (
SELECT SUM(-h.value_ini - h.purchase + h.sold + h.value_fin)
FROM   hist_portfolio AS h
WHERE  h.comp_id = r.comp_id
 AND h.port_id = r.port_id 
 AND h.exte_id = r.cate_id
 AND h.type_id = v_type_rel_aux
 AND h.hcar_day > v_date_month_before
 AND h.hcar_day <= v_date_base)     FROM   Month_Table r   WHERE  type = 1;
```

Result (after update), all the same value of  Seq 3:]

```
Seq     monthly 
1   -29841,23
2   -29841,23
3   -29841,23
4   -29841,23
```

I don't see the cause of the problem...
Does PostgreSQL have different rules on UPDATE?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `FROM` clause from Postgres:

```
UPDATE Month_Table r
    SET variacao_mes_rs = (
SELECT SUM(-h.value_ini - h.purchase + h.sold + h.value_fin)
FROM   hist_portfolio AS h
WHERE  h.comp_id = r.comp_id
 AND h.port_id = r.port_id 
 AND h.exte_id = r.cate_id
 AND h.type_id = v_type_rel_aux
 AND h.hcar_day > v_date_month_before
 AND h.hcar_day <= v_date_base)  
WHERE  type = 1;
```

The `FROM` clause in an `UPDATE` behaves differently in the two databases, as you have discovered.

Comment: You're correct! 
I'm so used to the MSSQL syntax that I would never realize. Thank you!

Comment: How can I do an update with join in PostgreSQL? In this case I must have a FROM clause, right?

Comment: @javaMan . . . The subquery is more convenient because of the aggregation.

Comment: @javaMan . . . I don't understand.  The subquery is never returning more than one row.  It is an aggregation query with no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Sorry.. I confused with other problem. It worked in this case.